# Performance SELECT float data type as key

Tags: database

I have two columns as float data type (lat, lng) that are my keys.

```
 lat       long      address
-21,5110  -48,6670   Itápolis, Rodovia Laurentino Mascari - São Paulo
```

So, for performance reasons, I should to save the data as integer?

```
 lat     long    address
-215110  -486670   Itápolis, Rodovia Laurentino Mascari - São Paulo
```

Answer (score 1):

If your table is very big and you need to consider all possibilities to save memory, you can do it so. However; you should take into account that the integer data type may not fit all possible float values which will occur as a bug in a live system. I want to point out that you should also consider that the primary key values should not be changed in the future for practical reasons. It may cause high performance issues especially for a live database. Considering the data you provided, the lat & long may be changed for some reasons. I would prefer using integer (if possible) which also simplifies the select queries such as; `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Id=...` etc.

Comment: Thank you for you comments.

Comment: Thank you for you comments. The nature of the data latitude and longitude have range values -90 until 90 for latitude and -180 until 180 for longitude, the decimal part we are limiting to scale of 6. So we can represent with Integer data type in the range  -90,000,000 - 180,000,000. This is a cache table in Cassandra where the data expire after a specific time and we need a compose key to SELECT with lat and long. Thanks.